# Rails - Run an external program on a Paperclip attachment for processing and save the output attachment back to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

In my rails project, I need the user to upload a file (input_file) which I will process using an external application. Once, it is completed, I want to attach the processed file to the same model as a different attachment (output file).

I have been able to create a form and use paperclip to allow the user to upload the input_file to my model `FileProcessor`. Im not sure on the next step as to how do I call an executable on the input_file and save it as output_file.

Based on paperclip, once the file is upload, I can access the path via input_file.path

```
output_file = %w{external_app input_file.path out_file_name}

Class FileProcessor
 has_attached_file :input_file
 has_attached_file :output_file
```

Im confused as to where this call to run the external app be placed? in the model or in the controller (def create). Also, how do I work with paperclip to associate the output_file with the model without actually uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location for such code depends on what kind of business your external process does. With the requirements as depicted in the question, it would be as simple as this:

```
class FileProcessor < ActiveRecord
  ...
  after_validation do |fp|
    tmp_file = "/tmp/#{rand}"
    system "/usr/bin/awesome.sh #{fp.input_file.path} > #{tmp_file}"
    fp.output_file = File.open(tmp_file)
  end
  ...
end
```

I hope, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The example above gave me a good idea on how to go about implementing my final solution. I put the function in the model.